# Why does the Sprite not get destroyed 2D unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, unity3d-2dtools

Right now we work on a Infinity-Runner, and i got this weird bug. After something leaves the Screen it will be catched by a collider that destroys everything. And it works...almost. It will destroy the ground, Background stuff, enemys you jumped over but NOT the newly implemented "roadblocks".

Here is a picture how it looks like, the green placeholder is the roadblock-thingy
http://s4.postimg.org/8uaorv7ot/Bug.png
hope this might help in visualizing what im saying^^.

The Script i use for the Destroyed (the green box collider) is:

```
            void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Break is gonna happen");
        Debug.Break();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.transform.parent)
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

and this is the script for the roadblocks:

```
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Break ();
    }
}
```

so basically nothing that would ever disrupt the DestroyerScript. Its even far more simple than the script on the enemys...but they get destroyed.

Thanks in advance for your help, i can provide more information if need.
(ohh, and all the art in this pic is placeholderstuff^^)

Comment: I think: if you have some questions about unity3d you better shouldn't ask on stackoverflow.. try this: http://forum.unity-community.de

Comment: might try this... if the problem is unitybased... just thought i might have done a mistake based on my code.

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html and check the Colliders. Maybe you set a trigger, but you shouldnt. Also check whether the Colliders are all of the 2D type. That's all I can guess. Maybe it helps. Otherwise check the link above, because C# != C# at Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OnTriggerExit2D to trigger when your player leave the collider. And makesure you added a suitable collider2d to your sprite before
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerExit2D.html
I'm not use it before but I think it might works